# grails: trying to save utf-8 in mysql fails

Tags: mysql, grails, datasource

i'm trying to save text in utf-8 languages (hebrew-arabic-etc..) and it fails .. first it was giving me (????????) 
so i put this in dataSource.groovy 
dbCreate = "update" 
       url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        }
and i've convert the whole database and it's table to have collation utf-8 and charset  also..

it gives me error says

> ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
>   2012-07-01 21:54:25,969 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
>   java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
>          at com.ehs.GameNewsController$_closure4.doCall(GameNewsController.groovy:27)
>          at com.ehs.GameNewsController$_closure4.doCall(GameNewsController.groovy)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

so what is the wrong am I doing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error states clearly that there's a mixing of "latin1_swedish_ci" and "utf8_general_ci" collation. Please try checking again that you don't have any field in any table that is still in latin1_swedish_ci COLLATE.

Comment: but question remain.. if i let grails create table by him self it make the table latin by default!! why is that?

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab: you may try to drop the database, then re-create it again with Grails. The base of Grails' database operation is Hibernate, and even Hibernate can't change COLLATE of a pre-defined column.

Answer (score 2):

try with useUnicode=true

```
 jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

and take care to add

```
dataSource {
    ...
   dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   ...
```

Comment: if from within your mysql databse you run the mysql statement: ' SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "collation_database" ' what is the mysql answer?

Comment: it's +--------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name      | Value           |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| collation_database | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------+-----------------+

Comment: try to do dump of your database structure and look if latin1_swedish_ci appair somewhere

Comment: work when i changed the column my self but question remain.. if i let grails create table by him self it make the table latin by default!! why is that?

Comment: ok nvm .. i created db with default charset utf-8 thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Linux. Change of tables engine to InnoDB helped me.